# System of equations to parametric form.

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I go from a system of equations to parametric form for a line?

For example, if I have $$\begin{cases} x+z = 0 \\ y=3 \end{cases}$$

How can I get that to the parametric form? $$(x,y,z) = (a,b,c) + t(d,e,f)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $z=t$, then
$$r(t)=(-t,3,t)=(0,3,0)+t(-1,0,1)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$(x,y,z) = (a,b,c) + t(d,e,f)$$

$$(x,y,z)=(a+td,b+te,c+tf)\forall t\in\mathbb R$$

Now since, $y=3$ is constant, $b+te$ is constant, but $t$ is variable. Thus, we need to make $e=0$. That leaves us with $b=3$.

Now $x=-z$,so $a+td=-c-tf$ for all values of $t$. Of course, $d=-f$ and $a=-c$.

Therefore one parameterized form would be $(x,y,z)=(0,3,0)+t(1,0,-1)$

$(1,3,-1)+t(-2,0,2)$ is valid as well.